# Raise forbidden attributes error in staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

Is it possible to configure a Rails 4 app to raise `ActionController::UnpermittedParameters` errors in staging? If so, how would one do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour can be changed by changing the `config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters` property in your environment files. If set to `:log` the unpermitted attributes will be logged, if set to `:raise` an exception will be raised.

https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters